# Initialize agGrid in AngularJS TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ag-grid

In a pure JS app you initialize agGrid like this:

```
var agGrid = require('ag-grid');

(function(angular) {

    agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular1(angular);

    angular.module('myApp', []);
```

I can't figure out how to initialize it with an AngularJS TypeScript app. I've tried this:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import * as agGrid from 'ag-grid/main';

agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular1(angular);

angular.module('myApp', []);
```

I'm pretty sure the initialization code is in the wrong place, but I'm not sure where to put it?

Comment: please refer this link - https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angularjs-data-grid/#basic-angularjs-1-x-example

Comment: I'd expect it to be done like you did. Do you have problems with this approach? You will need also to add agGrid module to myApp.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

```
import { initialiseAgGridWithAngular1 } from 'ag-grid-community';
initialiseAgGridWithAngular1(angular);
angular.module('myApp', ['agGrid']);
```